# broadcom BMC4322 using broadcom-wl-dkms driver doe not allow change of MAC address

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, arch-linux

I am trying to spoof the MAC address of my device. After much research I have discovered that the default driver for the BMC4322 network card uses the broadcom-wl driver as default and a suggested alternative is broadcom-wl-dkms. When i try to change the mac address using the guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing), i get the error

> [ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system

However the issue is not that there are too many open files in the system, it is a limitation of the highly restrictive driver by broadcom. Anybody have a plausible workaround?

Output of lspci -vnn | grep -i net

> 00:0a.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet [10de:0ab0] (rev b1)
>   03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)

Comment: Have you tried to set the first octet of MAC address to '02'?

Comment: 1. Have you tried changing the MAC address while your interface is **down**? 2. **If** that does not work, what are the Vendor:Product codes of your wifi driver? *lspci -vnn | grep -i net*

Comment: @MariusmatutiaeI have tried editing it while the interface was down. Same result.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat the problem is with permissions and not with the MAC address itself because i tried by just changing on digit in the MAC id and that didnt wor either